# ffmpeg select all files with extension and spaces in filenames

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to read all videos from folder and create thumbs from them. My video have spaces in filenames.

When I run this command I get:

```
FOR %I in (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i %I -ss 1 -vframes 1 -vf scale="200:-1" seek/%~nI.png
```

For example video is:

foo test.mp4

```
 foo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This isn't an ffmpeg problem. This is a problem with your shell environment. Please supply lots more info about your setup. Windows or Linux? Bash or Zsh? etc. Please don't make us guess - tell us everything relevant!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what environment you are running in, but in most cases it is sufficient to put double quotes around the variable:

```
FOR %I in (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%I" -ss 1 -vframes 1 -vf scale="200:-1" seek/%~nI.png
```

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names) question may be relevant.